# Date Arithmetic

Tags: haskell

```
addDays :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int)
addDays (dd,mm,yy) daystoadd =
    let yearType =  if((yy `mod` 4 ==0) && ((yy `mod` 100 /=0)||(yy `mod` 400 ==0)))
                        then [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
                    else [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        sumYear = (sum yearType)
        daysGone =sum ( (take (mm-1) ) yearType ) + dd
        totalDays = daysGone   + daystoadd
        yearsOverflow = totalDays `div` sumYear                                                  
        totalDays1 = totalDays `mod` sumYear


    year = yy+yearsOverflow
    monthsGone =last ( takeWhile (\x -> sum x <=totalDays1) ((inits(yearType) ) ) )


    daysofMonth = if (totalDays1 - (sum monthsGone) == 0) 
                        then ( yearType!!(mm-1) ) 
                  else if (totalDays1 <= (yearType!!(mm-1)) )                  
                        then totalDays1 
                  else (totalDays1 - (sum monthsGone) )

    noofMonths = if (monthsGone/= [])
                    then if ( ((length monthsGone) )>12) 
                            then ((length monthsGone)+1-12 ) 
                        else if( (last monthsGone) == daysofMonth )
                            then ( (length monthsGone) )                                                                                                                                                                                           --then ( (length monthsGone)+2 )
                        else ( (length monthsGone)+1 )                               
                 else  (length monthsGone) +1                                                 

in (daysofMonth,noofMonths, year)
```

I have written this function to add number of days to a date. But if i want to add 400 days from 1st may 2000, whenever it crosses 31st dec it uses the same months of leap year. How to use the non leap year months again?

Another problem I'm facing is the months with 30 days there month changes to next month on the last day of the month.

Any suggestions?

the way Dan Robertson explained 
i did this

```
import Data.List



isLeapYear :: Int -> Bool
isLeapYear x = ((x `mod` 4 ==0) && ((x `mod` 100 /=0)||(x `mod` 400 ==0)))



yearLength :: Int -> Int
yearLength n = if (isLeapYear n) then 366 else 365


monthLength :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
monthLength mm yy =  
let months = if isLeapYear yy 
                then  [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
            else [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
in months


leftInMonth :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
leftInMonth (dd,mm,yy) = ( (monthLength mm yy) !! (mm-1)  )  - dd     + 1     


daysSinceYearBegan :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
daysSinceYearBegan (dd,mm,yy) =if(mm==1)
                            then dd
                           else
                            dd + sum( take (mm-1)  (monthLength mm yy) ) 



leftInYear :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int
leftInYear (dd,mm,yy) = yearLength (yy) - (daysSinceYearBegan (dd,mm,yy) ) +1



addDays :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int)
addDays (dd,mm,yy) days =  
                        if ( days >= leftInYear (dd,mm,yy))
                            then addDays (1,1,(yy+1)) (days- (leftInYear (dd,mm,yy)) )                            
                        else if ( days >= leftInMonth (dd,mm,yy)  )
                                then if((mm)<=12 ) 
                                        then addDays (dd,mm+1,yy) (days- (leftInMonth (dd,mm,yy) ) )
                                      else addDays (1,1,yy+1) (days- (leftInMonth (dd,mm,yy) ) )                                     
                        else ( (dd + days),mm,yy)
```

Comment: I think you try to do too much in one function, and furthermore it is very imperatively written.

Comment: Date and time arithmetic is notoriously difficult to get right (in any language). Have you considered using Haskell's [built-in functions and data types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) for this purpose?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i'm told to do like this only.

Comment: @MarkSeemann cant use those

Comment: Why not? It's part of GHC's base library.

Comment: I honestly can not imagine that you should do it like that, since it is very *un*-Haskell to write functions like that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do u suggest i should go about?

Comment: @AlexiaDesouza: well for instance you write the entire condition to check if a year is a leap year, you can separate that in a new function `isLeapYear`, then you can construct a function `getDaysOfMonth` that uses the `isLeapYear`, etc. and so build up the function based on other functions.

Comment: @AlexiaDesouza - this may be horrible from a performance perspective, but you might simplify your problem (and the way you are thinking about it) if you figured out how to get the date of the next day, and then you could simply call this recursively until you get to n = 0.

Comment: Might be simpler just to convert the dates into a serial number, do your operations with simple addition/subtraction on the serial number and convert back to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a sketch of how to solve the problem. We will stick to the Gregorian calendar (so things like when a leap year is and what the months are are fixed).

We need a datatype for dates.

```
data Date = Date {year :: Int, month :: Int, day :: Int }
```

You could use smaller types for month and day but I don’t see a good reason to limit years. You could also use a month type which has variants for January, February etc. We will number months from 1 to 12.

How many days are in a year?

```
leapYear n = n `mod` 4 == 0 && (n `mod` 100 /= 0 || n `mod` 400 == 0)
yearLength n = if leapYear n then 366 else 365
```

How many days are in a month?

```
monthLength year month = months !! month where
  months = if leapYear year then months2 else months1
  months1 = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  months2 = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
```

Now how do we add some days to a date?
First we work out how many years to move on. Then how many months. Then how many days. So we want to know how many days are left in a month or year.

```
leftInMonth (Date year month day) = monthLength year month - day + 1
daysSinceYearBegan (Date year month day) = previousMonths + day - 1 where
 previousMonths = sum [monthLength m | m <- [1..month - 1]]
leftInYear date = yearLength (year date) - daysSinceYearBegan date
```

Now to add days:

```
addDays date 0 = date
addDays (Date year 1 1) days
  | days < 0 = undefined
  | days >= yearLength year = addDays (Date (year+1) 1 1) (days - yearLength year)
addDays d@(Date year month day) days
  | days < 0 = undefined
  | days >= leftInYear d = addDays (Date (year+1) 1 1) (days - leftInYear d)
  | days >= leftInMonth year month = addDays (if month == 12 then Date (year+1) 1 1) else Date year (month+1) 1) (days - leftInMonth year month)
  | otherwise = Date year month (day + days)
```

I’m not sure that works perfectly but should give you something more reasonable to work from